# Why is there a nested pointer inside a C struct definition?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, syntax

I'm working through Learn C The Hard Way and am struggling to understand something in Exercise 16: Structs And Pointers To Them.

```
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}
```

I understand that struct Person returns a pointer (*person_create) to the start of the struct. But why is there a second struct definition to Person immediately nested inside? Pointing to *who?

Can somebody shed some light on this for me. Or point me towards a better explanation of struct definitions in C.

Comment: We are missing (but could guess) the definition of `struct Person`

Comment: Nope. The `Person_create` function returns a pointer to a `Person`. The `who` variable holds the value that's returned by the function. You allocate the memory, and save a copy of the location the memory is at. You then set the various fields of this struct before finally returning the location of the allocated memory, which is in this case, the start of a `Person`. (you get the hang of them with continued use) :) - Pointers have a rough analogy to page numbers in a book - they tell you where to find something, with the added advantage of telling (by the pointer's type) what will be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I understand that `struct Person` returns a pointer (`*person_create`)*

Wait, it's not what you think, or at least you don't say it that way....

Here, `person_create()` is a **function**, which returns a pointer to `struct Person`. This is **not** a definition of `struct Person`.

Now, that said, coming to your actual quetion, `struct Person *who` **does not** define the `struct Person`, rather, it defines a variable `who` which is a pointer to `struct Person`.

For ease of understanding, consider `int someRandomVariable = 0`. It does not define `int`, right? It defines a variable `someRandomVariable` of type `int`.

Comment: Yeah. Using the words "I understand" in this instance is bit optimistic. I'm really not sure what's going on.

Comment: Thanks btw. That's helping. Will write some comments to it and spend some time thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a pointer of type `struct Person *`, in other words a pointer to a `struct Person`.

In particular here the pointer you will return is named `who`, as you can understand from the declaration `struct Person * who = ...` . Therefore, you need to allocate memory for the variable `who`, which you will fill, and return a pointer to.